# How to iteratively build a panel data set of past events with data measured at the time of the event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to build a model to predict the winner of professional tennis matches. I have scraped data on players, and past matches. However, the data that I have is representative of the players current information, and I would like to know the traits of the player at the time of the match.

For example, height isn't subject to change through time, but I would like to know their age at the time of the match, and their record at the time of the match (rather than knowing their current age and record).

I have tried to set up a simple illustrated example below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'winning_player': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
    'losing_player': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'height_winner': [74, 76, 75, 74],
    'height_loser': [69, 69, 70, 78],
    'age_winner': [28, 29, 37, 28],
    'age_loser': [34, 34, 23, 29],
    'date_of_match': ['01-02-2003', '03-10-2005', '20-12-2012', '03-03-2015'],
    'A_player_wins': [0, 0, 0, 1],
    'B_player_wins': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'A_player_losses': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'B_player_losses': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'A_player_birth_year': [1990, 1989, 1981, 1990],
    'B_player_birth_year': [1984, 1984, 1995, 1989],
    'A_age_at_match': [13, 16, 31, 25],
    'B_age_at_match': [19, 21, 17, 26]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)
```

What I would like to do is generate new columns for the record of the winning player and losing player at the time of the match. I would ideally do this by tallying which of the players won and lost previously in the dataset. Additionally for age, I have the current age of the player, but I would like to know how old they were at the time of the match.

In this example, `'winning_player':'A'` is the only individual who appears twice. How can I go about creating the relevant data and adding it to the dataframe? Is this something that using classes would solve? I am very new to python and come from a background in R, so I am not very familiar with OOP.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: In the toy example I included, there would be additional columns added for `wins` and `losses` of each player. The first row would start with everyone having 0s, but in the fourth row, player A would have 1 win from before. Additionally, there would be an added column for `age_at_time_of_match`, so `birth_year` would be 2018 - `age`, and then year of match - birth_year would get age at match time. Does that make sense?

Comment: can you include the additional expected columns in your question?